# SystemError: <class 'cv2.CascadeClassifier'> returned a result with an exception set

Tags: python, opencv

Help, when I try to run the following code,

```
import cv2 as cv

img = cv.imread('Photos/person.jpeg')
cv.imshow('person', img)
gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv.imshow('gray', gray)
haar_cascade = cv.CascadeClassifier('haar_face.xml')
    
faces_rect = haar_cascade.dectectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.1, minNeighbors=3)

cv.waitKey(0)
```

I get the error that the cascade classifier returned a result with an exception set.

I couldn't find anything on google about this error and I need help on what this means.I would really really appreciate any help :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.